# How to push values of each row to the array?

Tags: javascript

I have editable datatable and I want to updatee each row seperatly. Below you can see my js code where I try to push selected rows to the array. Then I will send it to php to proccess. But I can't choose specifi row to select. Array returns empty. How can I fix that?

HTML

```
<tbody>
<?php
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
 <form>
  <tr>
  <!-- EKN -->
  <td id="id" style="display:none;"><?php echo $row['Id']?></td>
  <td id="urunAciklama" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['UrunAciklama']?></td>
  <td id="miktar" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['Miktar']?></td>
  <td id="birimFiyati" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['BirimFiyati']?></td>
  <td id="satirTutari" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['SatirTutari']?></td>
  <td id="KdvOrani" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['KdvOrani']?></td>
  <td>
  <span class="table-remove"><button type="button" id="updateBtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0" onclick="updateInvoice('<?php echo $row['Id']?>')">Güncelle</button></span>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </form>
<?php  } //EoF While ?>
</tbody>
```

JS

```
function updateInvoice(ID){
 var faturaHareket=[];
  $(function(){
   $("click", function() {
     faturaHareket = [];
     $("table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
     var $tr = $(this);
     ('#updateBtn').click(function () {
      faturaHareket.push({
       id: Number($tr.find("#id").text()),
       urunAciklama: $tr.find("#urunAciklama").text(),
       miktar: $tr.find("#miktar").text(),
       birimFiyati: $tr.find("#birimFiyati").text(),
       satirTutari: $tr.find("#satirTutari").text(),
       kdvOrani: $tr.find("#kdvOrani").text()
       });
      });
     });
     console.clear();
     console.log(JSON.stringify(faturaHareket));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one problem with your code.

1. change all id in tr to classes for a good reason.
2. remove onclick from update button in html attach
3. update button listeners in js.

Please follow below code after changes:

```
 <tbody>
    <?php
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>
     <form>
      <tr>
      <!-- EKN -->
      <td class="id" style="display:none;"><?php echo $row['Id']?></td>
      <td class="urunAciklama" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['UrunAciklama']?></td>
      <td class="miktar" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['Miktar']?></td>
      <td class="birimFiyati" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['BirimFiyati']?></td>
      <td class="satirTutari" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['SatirTutari']?></td>


        <td class="KdvOrani" class="pt-3-half" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $row['KdvOrani']?></td>
          <td>
          <span class="table-remove"><button type="button" class="updateBtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">Güncelle</button></span>
           </td>
          </tr>
         </form>
        <?php  } //EoF While ?>
        </tbody>
```

JS

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.updateBtn').on('click', function(){
faturaHareket = [];
             var $tr =  $(this).closest('tr');
        faturaHareket.push({
               id: Number($tr.find(".id").text()),
               urunAciklama: $tr.find(".urunAciklama").text(),
               miktar: $tr.find(".miktar").text(),
               birimFiyati: $tr.find(".birimFiyati").text(),
               satirTutari: $tr.find(".satirTutari").text(),
               kdvOrani: $tr.find(".kdvOrani").text()
               });


           })
            })
```

Comment: But you don't loop the whole table, the code doesn't work.